# Cloud Endpoints Framework 2.0 Pip installation Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pip, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am trying to **migrate to Cloud Endpoints Frameworks 2.0** for App Engine from v1 in **Python**

When I pip install `pip install -t lib google-endpoints --ignore-installed`, I get an error

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-blaNgj/pycrypto/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-E6OxwC-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --home=/tmp/tmp_5iRxU" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-blaNgj/pycrypto
```

How to fix this?

I have also tried `sudo pip install -t lib google-endpoints --ignore-installed`, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to read the error message you pasted, since it's all on one line, but I *think* the issue you're having may be due to being on a Mac and not having either XCode or the XCode command line tools installed.

Try running 'gcc' at the command line and seeing if it says you need to install something.